# Empty braces appearing when using nested layouts in ASP.NET Core

Tags: razor, asp.net-core

In an ASP.NET Core application I have a `_Layout.cshtml` file that defines 2 sections, both in the `<head>` of the layout like this:

```
<head>
    @RenderSection("CSS", required: false)

    @RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)
</head>
<body>
    @RenderBody()
</body>
```

I'm trying to create a layout for certain views to use that will be nested, it consists of this:

```
@{
    Layout = "_Layout";
}

<h1>@ViewBag.Title</h1>

@Html.ValidationSummary()

@BodyContent {
    @RenderBody()
}

@section CSS {
    @RenderSection("CSS", required: false)
}

@section Scripts {
    @RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)
}
```

And Views needed this have their Layout defined to use this Layout instead of _Layout. The problem is that any View that uses this Layout has `{}` appended to the end of the content, and I cannot find where it is coming from. This appears regardless of whether or not the View defines a CSS and/or Scripts section, and wasn't appearing prior to including the new Layout in between the main _Layout and individual Views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed,

```
@BodyContent {
    @RenderBody()
}
```

Should just be:

```
@BodyContent
    @RenderBody()
```